# Exponentially weighting random variables in Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

The Random Variables in my Gaussian Process are indexed by time.

Therefore I would like to exponentially weight the random variables. This would make the inferred posterior function more constrained by 'recent' random variables and less so by 'older' ones.

I want to do this is so that extrapolated predictions are highly influenced by recent values.

Can anyone help me on how to approach this problem?

**edit**

Imagine a Gaussian Process formed by the collection of random variables X1, X2, ... X700. (In this scenario 1..700 represents hour1, hour2... hour700)

I would like to extrapolate the response values for X701...X710.

I have prior knowledge that X701..X710 will be highly influenced by X690..X700. (the process also has periodic structure throughout X1..X700)

How do I encode this belief in the model?

Comment: Can you add more information? I'm not sure this can be answered at present.